# How do I get my wrongfully flagged website unblocked when MetaMask won't react to issues on GitHub as far back as 2019?

Tags: security, phishing

Through potential customers I have been told that my website features the warning "Ethereum Phishing Detection".

Using the [phishing detection utility](https://metamask.github.io/eth-phishing-detect/) I am told the following:

"*This domain was blocked for its similarity to auctus.org, a historical phishing target.*"

My domain is **dictus.dk** and has been registered to us since [2003](https://who.is/whois/dictus.dk). **auctus.org** seems to only have been around since [2017](https://who.is/whois/auctus.org).

As per MetaMask instructions, I am to log my case [here](https://github.com/metamask/eth-phishing-detect/issues) if I believe it to be wrongfully marked as a scam. And so I did. [2 months ago](https://github.com/MetaMask/eth-phishing-detect/issues/8307).

Looking back at the issues present on their GitHub they stretch all the way to 2019 without any sign of them being handled.

I contacted [MetaMask support](https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/) for help. They told me to reach out to the broader community on stack exchange, as, and I quote the support here: "*Some of them might have had a similar experience with a website being blocked*"

So I ask you, the broader community:

1. Have any of you had a similar experience with a website being blocked?
2. How can I resolve the issue when the recommended approach of reporting the case seems unhandled since 2019?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted MetaMask support again and they created a support ticket for me. They added my website to their whitelist a few days later: https://github.com/MetaMask/eth-phishing-detect/pull/8989/commits